# HAProxy + Percona XtraDB Cluster

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, load-balancing, haproxy, percona

I am attempting to setup HAproxy in conjunction with Percona XtraDB Cluster on a series of 3 EC2 instances. I have found a few tutorials online dealing with this specific issue, but I am a bit stuck.

Both the Percona servers and the HAproxy servers are running ubuntu 12.04. The HAProxy version is 1.4.18,

When I start HAProxy I get the following error: Server pxc-back/db01 is DOWN, reason: Socket error, check duration: 2ms.

I am not really sure what the issue could be. I have verified the following:

1. EC2 security groups ports are open
2. Poured over my config files looking for issues. I currently do not see any.
3. Ensured that xinetd was installed
4. Ensured that I am using the correct ip address of the mysql server.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Here are my current config

Load Balancer

**/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg**

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1 local0
  log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
  maxconn 4096
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  debug
  #quiet
  daemon

defaults
  log global
  mode http
  option tcplog
  option dontlognull
  retries 3
  option redispatch
  maxconn 2000
  contimeout 5000
  clitimeout 50000
  srvtimeout 50000

frontend pxc-front
  bind 0.0.0.0:3307
  mode tcp
  default_backend pxc-back

frontend stats-front
  bind 0.0.0.0:22002
  mode http
  default_backend stats-back

backend pxc-back
  mode tcp
  balance leastconn
  option httpchk
  server db01 10.86.154.105:3306 check port 9200 inter 12000 rise 3 fall 3

backend stats-back 
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  stats uri /haproxy/stats
```

MySql Server

**/etc/xinetd.d/mysqlchk**

```
# default: on
# description: mysqlchk
service mysqlchk
{
# this is a config for xinetd, place it in /etc/xinetd.d/
        disable = no
        flags           = REUSE
        socket_type     = stream
        port            = 9200
        wait            = no
        user            = nobody
        server          = /usr/bin/clustercheck
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        #only_from       = 0.0.0.0/0
        # recommended to put the IPs that need
        # to connect exclusively (security purposes)
        per_source      = UNLIMITED
}
```

MySql Server

**/etc/services**

Added the line mysqlchk        9200/tcp                # mysqlchk

MySql Server

**/usr/bin/clustercheck**

```
# GNU nano 2.2.6 File: /usr/bin/clustercheck
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script to make a proxy (ie HAProxy) capable of monitoring Percona XtraDB Cluster nodes properly
#
# Author: Olaf van Zandwijk <olaf.vanzandwijk@nedap.com>
# Documentation and download: https://github.com/olafz/percona-clustercheck
#
# Based on the original script from Unai Rodriguez
#

MYSQL_USERNAME="testuser"
MYSQL_PASSWORD=""
ERR_FILE="/dev/null"
AVAILABLE_WHEN_DONOR=0

#
# Perform the query to check the wsrep_local_state
#
WSREP_STATUS=`mysql --user=${MYSQL_USERNAME} --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} -e "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_local_state';" 2>${ERR_FILE} | awk '{if (NR!=1){print $2}}' 2>${ERR_FILE}`

if [[ "${WSREP_STATUS}" == "4" ]] || [[ "${WSREP_STATUS}" == "2" && ${AVAILABLE_WHEN_DONOR} == 1 ]]
then
    # Percona XtraDB Cluster node local state is 'Synced' => return HTTP 200
    /bin/echo -en "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
    /bin/echo -en "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
    /bin/echo -en "\r\n"
    /bin/echo -en "Percona XtraDB Cluster Node is synced.\r\n"
    /bin/echo -en "\r\n"
else
    # Percona XtraDB Cluster node local state is not 'Synced' => return HTTP 503
    /bin/echo -en "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable\r\n"
    /bin/echo -en "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
    /bin/echo -en "\r\n"
    /bin/echo -en "Percona XtraDB Cluster Node is not synced.\r\n"
    /bin/echo -en "\r\n"
fi
```

Comment: what does `curl -I localhost:9200` return when run on one of the db cluster nodes? HAproxy will look for a 200 HTTP return code when running that check in order for it to mark the server up.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure the following steps and post the results here.

1. xinetd is running.
2. Create the mysql test user `testuser` as you mentioned
3. verify listening tcp port(9200) by `netstat -nlt`
4. If you have enabled iptables, please allow port 9200
5. if the port is open and in listen state, install telnet client in percona node and try to telnet by `telnet 127.0.0.1 9200`
6. If the xinetd is working, you should see the http response.
7. if not, execute `/usr/bin/clustercheck`

Once you done all this, please post the results here.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem where `telnet 127.0.0.1 9200` gave 503 Server unavailable response, but when I executed `/usr/bin/clustercheck` as root it showed that everything was fine.

With this command I was able to execute clustercheck as user `nobody` and got real MySQL error to `/tmp/cluster.log`:

`sudo -H -u nobody bash -c "/usr/bin/clustercheck clustercheckuser clustercheckpassword! 0 /tmp/cluster.log"`

And `/tmp/cluster.log` contained:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)
```

Problem was that directory where `mysql.sock` was located didn't have execute (+x) flag on it and therefore wasn't readably by user `nobody` and fix was:

`chmod o+x /var/run/mysql`